# Using self-referential arrays, polygons are invisible

Tags: java, arrays, graphics, draw, polygon

I used an array that refers to previous elements in the same array to determine what the next value will be. This is so that I can get relative values for position when drawing polygons.
There are no reported syntax errors, but the triangles I use here in the example are either invisible or don't exist.

For this example, I would like to make small black triangles randomly scattered in the top half of the window without regard for the window's edges and the other triangles.
The following is the code which includes an example of what I'm trying to achieve, but without using a self-referential array (I wrote this in BlueJ and have never written anything outside of BlueJ. I don't know how to write continuous code so please bear with me. I wrote where each of the two classes begin after each // :

//first class

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class patterns {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Example");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        example p = new example();
        f.add(p);
        f.setSize(400,400);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

//next class

```
     import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
public class example extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //The following is the part of the code that doesn't work.
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        int x=0;//this x is used for the following while loop
        int[] xC = new int[3];//these are the x coordinates of the random triangles
        int[] yC = new int[3];//these are the y coordinates of the random triangles
        while(x<14){//this while loop is used to make many triangles
            xC[0]= (int)Math.random()*400;
            xC[1]= xC[0]+(int)Math.random()*20;
            xC[2]= xC[1]+(int)Math.random()*4;
            yC[0]= (int)Math.random()*200;
            yC[1]= yC[0]-(int)Math.random()*10;
            yC[2]= yC[0]-(int)Math.random()*3;
            g.fillPolygon(xC,yC,3);//I changed this to fillPolygon
            x++;//this is so the loop will eventually end
        }
        //the following is the manual part that does work.
        int[] xCe = new int[3];//this is the array of x coordinates for the triangle
        xCe[0]= 200;
        xCe[1]= 210;
        xCe[2]= 213;
        int[] yCe = new int[3];//this is the array of y coordinates for the triangle
        yCe[0]= 300;
        yCe[1]= 295;
        yCe[2]= 299;
        g.fillPolygon(xCe,yCe,3);//this polygon appears properly
        //everything after this is just to help explain after compiling
        g.drawString("There should be a whole bunch of little triangles that look",20,320);
        g.drawString("sort of like this one, but on the top half of this window.", 40,340);
        g.drawLine(170,270,200,290);
        g.drawLine(194,289,200,290);
        g.drawLine(197,285,200,290);
        g.drawString("this one",140,260);
    }
}
```

What is causing them to be invisible? I would like for them to be visible. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Is it the self-referential arrays? Is that not allowed for fillPolygon()?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, the question is: what is causing them to be invisible? I would like for them to be visible. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Is it the self-referential arrays?

Comment: You wrote the following: "*The following is the code which includes an example of what I'm trying to achieve, but **without using a self-referential array***"

Comment: The code also includes those self-referential arrays that aren't working. I'm using them so that I can have a variety of triangles scattered about the screen. When I don't use the self-referential array I have to write the coordinates of the polygon manually, and so it's not random, but that's the example that does work.

Comment: I'm confused: are you showing us working or non-working example of your code?

Comment: It has both. If the code is compiled it will show a small triangle in the bottom half of the screen whose coordinates I manually wrote in.That part worked, but it's manually written so it's no good, because I want tons of random (not just translated) triangles. The top half is blank, but that's where there are supposed to be many triangles. The int arrays xC and yC don't work; the int arrays xCe and yCe do work but are manual.

Comment: This needs proofreading before asking the question. The indentation is horrible. I can't understand the purpose of, e.g.        `while(x<14){
        g.drawPolygon(xC,yC,3);
        x++;
    }`. What is `x` and is it necessary?

Comment: Please check your brackets. It seems that the *manual* part is outside of any method.  I also noticed that you use `g.drawPolygon(xC,yC,3);` and `g.fillPolygon(xCe,yCe,3);` **the two different methods**.  If you want a fair comparison use `fillPolygon` in **both** cases.

Comment: Do you mean that I should put comments throughout the code to explain each line and then edit my post so that the question is more clear with the new knowledge I have gained from discussing it with you guys? This is my first post and I'm new to coding, sorry I'm pretty terrible at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize the values in your arrays like this:

```
xC[0]= (int)Math.random()*400;
```

But the cast happens before the multiplication, so the value returned by `Math.random()` (which will be less than 1) gets cast to an int, so it becomes `0*400`, therefore 0 gets stored into all the indices of your array.

To fix this, just put parentheses around the multiplication so it looks like:

```
xC[0]= (int)(Math.random()*400);
```

I should also note that your loop is just drawing the same triangle 14 times, so you still won't see a bunch of different triangles. To fix that, just put the code you use to generate your triangles inside of your loop, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    int[] xC = new int[3];
    xC[0] = (int) (Math.random() * 400);
    xC[1] = xC[0] + (int) (Math.random() * 200);
    xC[2] = xC[1] + (int) (Math.random() * 4);
    int[] yC = new int[3];
    yC[0] = (int) (Math.random() * 200);
    yC[1] = yC[0] - (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    yC[2] = yC[0] - (int) (Math.random() * 3);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillPolygon(xC,yC,3);
}
```

I'd also suggest giving your triangles a more uniform size (sides of < 3 and 4 are kind of small), perhaps generate a random value between a low and high number (e.g. 10 to 20). And maybe look into the `java.util.Random` class while you're at it.

Comment: WOW! You just fixed everything! Thank you so much! and now I have an explanation to so many other problems that I have had in the past!